# Flotr Y Axis Title

Tags: flotr

Hi In Flotr Playground (http://flotr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/flotr/playground/index.html) site also the Y Axis Title is appearing in a Horizontal Way

See the Image here http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=c57a22f

Please tell me how to resolve this ??

I want to have the Text in Vertical Style for Y axis Under my Charts .

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the option `HtmlText` by setting it to false.

Answer (score 1):

```
options = {"HtmlText": false, "yaxis": {"title": "abc", "titleAngle": 90}};
```

As Fabien Ménager mentioned, You need to turn off the HtmlText option. Then the title and the title angle can be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [quick start guide](http://solutoire.com/flotr/docs/quickstart/) 
Looks like you need to investigate a little more, and work out the solution by playing with the Flotr.draw() options